# Передача данных с клиента JavaScript на сервер PHP и обратно

Tags: javascript, форма

Разрабатываю приложение на *Ioniv v3*.
С помощью `this.http.post(url, body, options)` я отправляю успешно данные на сервер и он успешно их получает и обрабатывает, выдавая ответ в консоли.

Но как получить ответ от сервера в JS об успехе выполнения операции или перенести переменную или массив и использовать их дальше в JS?

Сейчас пытаюсь реализовать систему авторизации и регистрации. 
Говорят, что можно это сделать с помощью куки или токена, но инструкций найти не могу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый вечер. Есть 2 способа проверки правильности логина/пароля.
1. Можно, когда вы отправляете http запрос, на странице ответа разместить json, в котором будет оказан статус выполения входа.
2. Можно использовать протокол websocket (https://github.com/socketio/socket.io), который реализует как запросы пользователь-сервер, так и сервер-пользователь. Вы можете отправлять данные по этому протоколу и получить событие статуса входа там же.

Comment: Первый вариант еще слышал. Вот второй в первый раз встречаю. Можно предоставить пример работы первого варианта?

Comment: Пользовался этим материалом, очень хорошо расписано и объяснено [вот](https://code-live.ru/post/php-ajax-registration/)